# WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager NOT working without Localhost

Tags: mdm

WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager is working on localhost but i cant test this product on localhost cause i require to connect internet to test with my Android Phone . To do this test.
I opened my 9443 port to internet and i can connect my localhost with this link `https://[my_ip_address]:9443`
 Enterprise Mobility Manager Homepage getting correctly but when i click "Mobile Device Management Link" .its not redirecting me to login page.

Actually , on localhost its workin truely and i can see login page and i can login successfully.

**NOTES;**
1- i changed hostname in carbon.xml

```
 <HostName>localhost</HostName>
```

to

```
<HostName>[my_ip_address]</HostName>
```

and i changed localhosts in sso-idp-sonfig.xml
for ex;

```
<AssertionConsumerService>https://[my_ip_address]:9443/mdm/acs</AssertionConsumerService>
```

what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed up deployment and testing. For testing you don't have to change the `HostName`. It will automatically take the local ip for devices. But keep the sso-idp-config as above. Please follow the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/General+Server+Configurations) regarding this.

Comment: Can we test using local host if we don't have any MDM server.